# Continually try to insert random unique values into table

Tags: php, mysql

So, I've got a function that generates a random number in base 62, and I would like to attempt to insert a random unique number of length 7 into the table. I originally had the rows auto-increment as the values were input, but that involved a lot of inserting, selecting, and then updating the rows. Here's the new code so far that didn't work:

```
do {
    if (isset($query)) { mysqli_stmt_close($query); }
    $query = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO table1 value1=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 's', rand_64(7));
} while (!mysqli_stmt_execute($query));
mysqli_stmt_close($query);
```

My question is: can something like this be achieved, or would it be better to generate the random numbers, try a SELECT statement, and if the returned rows == 0, stop looping and insert the values?

Edit: I should note that it properly inserts the values if the value is unique (i.e. not already in the table), but it fails to insert if the value already exists.

Thanks very much. :)

Comment: Have you tried `ON DUPLICATE KEY` or `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: How many of these must you insert? Is this a one-time requirement, or will you need to do this repeatedly?

Comment: Fred: ON DUPLICATE KEY probably wouldn't work in this case, because I would need to know what number is generated. Mike: The user is uploading files, and this renames them with the random string generator so they can be linked to later. The end goal is to keep looping and trying to insert until no collision occurs.

Comment: would 'uniqid' and 'base_convert' or 'base64_encode' do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind the result of a function call or a literal to a prepared statement - it has to be a variable. If you assign the returned value of `rand_64()` to a variable before you bind it you should have more success.

Additionally, you only need to prepare the query once so you can take that out of the loop too.

This gives you:

```
if (isset($query)) { mysqli_stmt_close($query); }

$query = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO table1 set value1=?");

do {
    $rand = rand_64(7)
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 's', $rand);
} while (!mysqli_stmt_execute($query));

mysqli_stmt_close($query);
```

All that said, since you're generating the variable yourself and it's likely only one call to the database will be required, you're likely to get better overall performance by not using a prepared statement here.

Assuming your `rand_64()` function doesn't return any strings that include single quotes you get:

```
$success = true;
do {
    $rand = rand_64(7)
    $query = "INSERT INTO table1 set value1='$rand'";
    if (mysqli_query($connection, $query)) == true) {break;}
    if (mysqli_error($connection) != 1062) {
      $success = false;
      break;
    }
} while (true);
```

NB:

- I have corrected a syntax error in your SQL
- your `value1` must be marked unique, non-null.
- I haven't tested this code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried that code, and it should work, because mysqli_query returns true/false, right? But when I do that, it puts itself into an infinite loop. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Your original SQL query was wrong and generated a syntax error so the loop would continue for ever. I've corrected my snippet and added a check on the loop to break if the error is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward way to assign a random unique value to each row in a table:

```
SET @r = 0;

UPDATE table1
SET value1 = (@r:=@r+1)
ORDER BY RAND();
```

You get values from 1 to the number of rows in the table, but the values are distributed pseudo-randomly, not increasing like an auto-increment.